# Cannot get image in display ILI9341 LVGL v8.3, ESP32

Tags: c, platformio, esp-idf, lvgl

I am trying to display an image on an ILI9341 display using the LittlevGL library and an ESP32 board. I have connected the display and XPT2046 touch screen according to the pinout specified in my code, and I have correctly configured the display and touch screen drivers in the platformio.ini file. However, when I run the code, I get the following error message:
D (1272) intr_alloc: Connected src 16 to int 12 (cpu 0)␛[0m
'Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.'

I have checked the pinout and the driver configurations, but I am still unable to get the image to display on the screen. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? Here is my code:

```
#include "lvgl/lvgl.h"
#include "lvgl_esp32_drivers/lvgl_helpers.h"
#include "lvgl/examples/lv_examples.h"
#include "ili9341.h"
#include "xpt2046.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

#define LCD_WIDTH 320
#define LCD_HEIGHT 240

static void btn_event_cb(lv_event_t * e)
{
    lv_event_code_t code = lv_event_get_code(e);
    lv_obj_t * btn = lv_event_get_target(e);
    if(code == LV_EVENT_CLICKED) {
        static uint8_t cnt = 0;
        cnt++;

        /*Get the first child of the button which is the label and change its text*/
        lv_obj_t * label = lv_obj_get_child(btn, 0);
        lv_label_set_text_fmt(label, "Button: %d", cnt);
    }
}

void lv_example_get_started_1(void)
{
    lv_obj_t * btn = lv_btn_create(lv_scr_act());     /*Add a button the current screen*/
    lv_obj_set_pos(btn, 10, 10);                            /*Set its position*/
    lv_obj_set_size(btn, 120, 50);                          /*Set its size*/
    lv_obj_add_event_cb(btn, btn_event_cb, LV_EVENT_ALL, NULL);           /*Assign a callback to the button*/

    lv_obj_t * label = lv_label_create(btn);          /*Add a label to the button*/
    lv_label_set_text(label, "Button");                     /*Set the labels text*/
    lv_obj_center(label);
}

static void display_task(void *arg)
{
  // Initialize the display
  lv_init();
  lv_example_get_started_1();

  // Update the display continuously
  while (1) {
    lv_tick_inc(portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    lv_task_handler();
    vTaskDelay(portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}

void configure_drivers()
{
  lvgl_driver_init();
  
  static lv_disp_draw_buf_t draw_buf;
  static lv_color_t buf1[LCD_WIDTH * LCD_HEIGHT / 10];                        /*Declare a buffer for 1/10 screen size*/
  lv_disp_draw_buf_init(&draw_buf, buf1, NULL, LCD_WIDTH * LCD_HEIGHT / 10);  /*Initialize the display buffer.*/

  // Set the display and touch screen drivers in LVGL
  lv_disp_drv_t disp_drv;
  lv_disp_drv_init(&disp_drv);
  disp_drv.flush_cb  = ili9341_flush;
  disp_drv.draw_buf = &draw_buf;        /*Assign the buffer to the display*/
  disp_drv.hor_res = LCD_WIDTH;   /*Set the horizontal resolution of the display*/
  disp_drv.ver_res = LCD_HEIGHT;   /*Set the vertical resolution of the display*/
  lv_disp_drv_register(&disp_drv);
  /*
  lv_indev_drv_t indev_drv;
  lv_indev_drv_init(&indev_drv);
  indev_drv.type = LV_INDEV_TYPE_POINTER;
  indev_drv.read_cb = xpt2046_read;
  lv_indev_drv_register(&indev_drv);
  */
}


extern "C" void app_main()
{
  // Create a task to handle the display
  xTaskCreate(display_task, "display", 8192, NULL, 5, NULL);
}
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

[image]
I am using
Platformio
esp-idf 4.4.2
LVGL v8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to implement ESP32+ILLI9431 like you.

In my case, It is totally working fine with this. It is LVGL V7
https://github.com/lvgl/lv_port_esp32

However, when I tried to work with LVGL V8.
It is not working well.

I think there is a problem with LVGL V8 and ESP32 LCD driver.

So, you can check whether is any problem in your schematic with LVGL V7.
and then you can migrate into LVGL V8 if you want later

Answer (score 1):

change
`lv_disp_drv_t disp_drv;`
to
`static lv_disp_drv_t disp_drv;`
because the pointer to that memory is used much later, and the stack location is overwritten, a lot.

I'm struggling with finding versions of lvgl that work on esp32.
Currently I'm using lvgl_esp32_drivers @ 9fed1cc (with a manual fix to the assert that uses the non-existing SPI_HOST_MAX) and lvgl v8.3.3. With your example and a watchpoint to discover the variable on the stack, I finally got a button, thanks!